# How to enable systemd dhcp client logging?

Tags: networking, systemd, logs, dhcp

Trying to debug some systemd dhcp client behavior, but I can't figure out how to enable systemd-networkd debug logging.   Specifically I want to see the log_dhcp_client() log entries in src/libsystemd-network/sd-dhcp-client.c.

I've changed the systemd-networkd log level to debug as described in the first answer here:

https://superuser.com/questions/1187633/how-to-debug-systemd-networkd

but I still don't see any dhcp client debug messages in journalctl (or anywhere else).    (I even rebooted after enabling the debug as one reply said was needed.)

Running systemd v246 (v246.2+).    Any help greatly appreciated.   Thanks!!

Comment: Read `man rsyslog.conf` (`man syslog.conf`, `man -k syslog`, depending on your system flavor). I think you have to enable saving `DEBUG` messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more investigation, I learned that the problem was self-imposed!    My `journald.conf` (inherited from an OpenBMC-related project) contained settings:

```
MaxLevelStore=info
MaxLevelSyslog=info
```

So even when I configured systemd-networkd to log debug messages, they were not logged by journald or forwarded to syslog.    After changing the journald settings above to 'debug', I was then able to see my debug messages.

Hopefully my pain will help someone else avoid the same fate.

Answer (score 0):

This got me out of a hole troubleshooting a DHCP Client issue in Ubuntu when Netplan was misbehaving. I didn't initially know whether ***systemd-networkd*** was handling the DHCP client stuff or ***NetworkManager***'s own DHCP client as BOTH clients were generating leases!

So if only for the process of exclusion the following is offered if you're in a similar jam.

In `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` add a a `[logging]` section and in it add:

```
[logging]
#level=INFO
#level=DEBUG
domains=ETHER:DEBUG,DHCP4
```

I recommend using the final directive `domains` as this will limit the verbosity to exclusively DHCP details and not swamp you

Restart NeworkManager after changing its' conf file:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Specimen Output:

`journalctl -u NetworkManager.service | grep DHCP`

```
<SNIP>
NetworkManager[4833]: <debug> [16*.3488] dhcp-init: enabled DHCP client 'dhclient'
NetworkManager[4833]: <debug> [16*.3489] dhcp-init: enabled DHCP client 'internal'
NetworkManager[4833]: <debug> [16*.3489] dhcp-init: enabled DHCP client 'systemd' (undocumented internal plugin)
NetworkManager[4833]: <debug> [16*.3490] dhcp-init: enabled DHCP client 'nettools' (undocumented internal plugin)
NetworkManager[4833]: <info> [16*.3491] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
<SNIP>
```

Remark that without the additional level of "debug" detail, the feedback from the "info" level of logging would not reveal that NetworkManager was also invoking 'dhclient' which was driving me bananas trying to figure out how (2) sets of DHCP leases were being created and whether ***systemd-networkd*** or ***NetworkManager*** was authoritative. Appears ***Netplan*** was the cultprit in the end.

Anyhoo, it was a piggy to unpick, so felt was worth sharing what I learned to save others going down the same rabbit hole...